# ListView change text on item click

Tags: android, list, listview

I have a listview that is built from textviews.

If the user clicks an item list, the text of the clicked item will be changed, how can I do that?

I know how to add new item, but changing its text? How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with an [AdapterView.OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html). Implement the `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` method. The `view` you get passed here, is the `TextView` of the clicked item, so it should be enough to do

```
((TextView)view).setText("Hey, I've just been tapped on!");
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you need to add a [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) to your [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html):

```
mMyListView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    }
));
```

In the method [onItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) of the [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) there is an *view* parameter. It contains the row of the ListView which has been clicked.

With that view, you can get the TextView and then change the text:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
    tv.setText(...);
}
```

If your ListView cell only contains a TextView, you can safely cast the view directly into a TextView:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) view;
    tv.setText(...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 mListView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView mTextView = (TextView) view;
        mTextView.setText("TextView was Clicked");
    }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it will work if you have a simple Adapter:

```
mListView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView mTextView = (TextView) view;
        mTextView.setText("TextView was Clicked");
    }
));
```

But if you have a **custom view** you need to look for the View to change the text:

```
mListView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //TextView mTextView = (TextView) view;
        //mTextView.setText("TextView was Clicked");
        ((TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.description))).setText(""TextView was Clicked");
    }
));
```